# show EnumProperty in node

Tags: python, animation-nodes

Just like the Math node I want to create options like this:

[image]

However, in the original code of the math node, I can't find a line to make the options show up in the node. How do I do that?

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *
from ... base_types.node import AnimationNode
from ... tree_info import keepNodeLinks, keepNodeState


operationItems = [
    ("ADD", "Add", "A + B", "", 0),
    ("SUBTRACT", "Subtract", "A - B", "", 1),
    ("MULTIPLY", "Multiply", "A * B", "", 2),
    ("RECIPROCAL", "Reciprocal", "1 / A", "", 21),
    ("SNAP", "Snap", "snap A", "", 22)]


class EnumPropertyTest(bpy.types.Node, AnimationNode):
    bl_idname = "an_EnumPropertyTest"
    bl_label = "EnumProperty Test"

    def operationChanged(self, context):
        self.recreateInputSockets()
        executionCodeChanged()

    operation = EnumProperty(name="Operation", default="MULTIPLY",
                         items=operationItems, update=operationChanged)

    def create(self):
        pass

    def execute(self, write):
        pass

    @keepNodeState
    def recreateInputSockets(self):
        self.inputs.clear()
```

Now I have just this:

[image]

In case a quick link to the Math node helps:
https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/blob/master/nodes/number/float_math.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw properties into your node you have to implement the draw function:

```
def draw(self, layout):
    layout.prop(self, "operation", text = "Operation")
```

Comment: Ah, thx, Is that cause it actually has to redraw the 'image' when interacting?

Comment: yes. In fact, the draw function is called very often. Just put a print statement inside and look into the console how often it prints something (also try with Auto Execution enabled and disabled, because AN will redraw everything after execution). If you check the code of the panels etc, you'll see that this is the way it works in Blender, and it's quite powerful for dynamic UIs.